# Why does the US government fail to declare the recent Morsi coup of Egypt as a Coup?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, coup

It is clear from many media outlets and the ground facts that the [overthrow of the democratically elected leader of Egypt](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/rajan-menon/egypta-coup-is-what-it-is_b_3554607.html) was indeed a coup. But, the USA is [hesitant to declare it as a coup.](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/07/06/us-egypt-protests-west-hatred-idUSBRE9650HY20130706) What are the reasons, apart from the promised fund aid to Egypt, which deter the US from declaring this coup as a coup?

According to U.S. law, military aid must be suspended to Egypt as this is clearly a coup. Is it possible that the USA actually favors this coup and wants to replace the leader with its [own UN backed leader like El Baradei](http://www.globalpost.com/dispatch/news/afp/130706/mohamed-elbaradei-egypts-new-prime-minister)?

Comment: Short of some leaked secret memo, it's impossible to answer why US government's real reasons are, which makes the question not constructive since the only answers would be either speculations or guesses. The official stated reason is "this is Egypt's interal business", which is of course about as believable as a 4 dollar coin.

Comment: As an aside, there are wildly varied factions within "US government", from pro-Islamist ones friendly with Moslem Brotherhood to pragmatist "Kissingery" "US has no permanent friends and enemies, only national interests" to anti-Islamist ones. And they all change memberships based on many reasons, to boot.

Comment: @DVK If you can provide references for the officially stated reason, that would be a good answer to the question.

Comment: @YannisRizos - I don't even want to bother, frankly, precisely because the official reason is pure BS :)   If I cared enough, I'd post an actual good answer based on Stratfor evaluation of incorrect Western perceptions of Arab Spring in general and Morsi's rise in particular; but I'm unsure the multi-hour research effort is worth it at the moment. May be someone else will take this idea and run with it (I hope :). If the question stays open after a week, I'll see if I can sink the time in.

Comment: @DVK I would be really interested to know about this, do give the answer if you know it.

Comment: So, not to put too fine a point on it, but why should anyone care what the United States thinks?  I mean, first people b**h about the US being the world's policeman, but when the US *doesn't* take action on the internal affairs of a foreign power, its somehow a conspiracy?

Comment: @AffableGeek - "As a general rule, ... people ask for advice only in order not to follow it; or, if they do follow it, in order to have someone to blame for giving it." - Athos (Count De La Fere), "The Three Musketeers", Alexandre Dumas.

Comment: Related: http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2013/07/09/what-egyptians-think-obama-after-morsi-disaster/?intcmp=obinsite

Answer (score 1):

As per @Yannis's request:

> "The president condemned the ongoing violence across Egypt and expressed concern over the continued political polarization. **He reiterated that the United States is not aligned with, and does not support, any particular Egyptian political party or group**," a White House statement said. ([Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/07/06/us-egypt-protests-obama-idUSBRE9650GB20130706)).

This is for obvious reasons. Given that both anti-Mursi and pro-Mursi forces are able to muster huge protests, it's hard to say which side clearly has the expression of popular democratic will. Anything US will do will piss someone (or, as is typically the case in Middle East, **everyone**) off.

Comment: I had hoped you would put in a section about the White House preferring to pretend Egypt simply doesn't exist since it has become rather embarrassing for Obama.

Comment: @Ryathal - Well yeah. His side lost.